# Calculates product sequence not working [python]

Tags: python

This is a a function product_loop() which uses the
iterative programming logic (i.e. using loop) to calculate
product sequence for a number passed as parameter to the
function.

````
    count = 2
    arr = [1, 2]
    while count - 1 != n - 1:
        next_num = arr[count - 1] * arr[count - 2]
        arr.append(next_num)
        count += 1
    return arr[n - 1]
    pass
        pass```

I am getting indented errors, how do I fix this?
````

Comment: remove 'pass' and verify your code indentation

Comment: Are those random `pass` there? Also -- why not post the whole function definition (including the `def` line) instead of just part of it?

Answer (score 1):

`pass` is a no-op, it is used when you have to have something on the line but don't want anything to actually happen.

An example of when to use `pass` is in a try/except clause when you just want to continue running the program:

```
a = [0]
try:
    a[1] = 2
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Remove your `pass` statements and the code will run.

```
count = 2
arr = [1, 2]
while count - 1 != n - 1:
    next_num = arr[count - 1] * arr[count - 2]
    arr.append(next_num)
    count += 1
return arr[n - 1]
```